# Designate function with best mean square fit in form of $y(x) = ax + 2015$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

*Designate function with best mean square fit in form of $y(x) = ax + 2015$ given pairs $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), .., (x_n, y_n)$.*

I've many similar exercises like this to do but I don't know how to proceed :( I think I should take partial derivative with regard to $a$ and then try to find global minimum for this.

$\epsilon = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - x_i)^2 = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - ax_i - 2015)^2$

$\frac{\sigma}{\sigma a}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - ax_i - 2015)^2 = \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - ax_i)x_i = \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}-ax_i^2 + y_i $

I know that algorithms like gradient descent deal with this by simly getting partical derivative with regard to $x$ and moving in proper direction until minimum is found but I have no idea how to deal with this mathematically. 
For single hiperbole it's easy but I don't know how to find constant $a$ that minimizes whole sum. Also how should I eventually designate this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$, $\mathbf{y} = (y_1,\ldots,y_n)^T$, and $\mathbf{1}$ be the $n$-vector of all ones. Then your goal is to minimize

$$
f(a) = \frac{1}{n}\|\mathbf{y} - a\mathbf{x} - 2015\mathbf{1}\|^2 = \frac{1}{n}(\|\hat{\mathbf{y}}\|^2 - 2a\mathbf{x}^T\hat{\mathbf{y}} + a^2\|\mathbf{x}\|^2)
$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{y}} = \mathbf{y} - 2015\mathbf{1}$. We recognize the graph of $f$ as a parabola that opens upwards, so there exists a global minimum corresponding to the vertex of the parabola. Differentiating $f$ with respect to $a$ we get $f'(a) = -2\mathbf{x}^T\hat{\mathbf{y}} + 2a\|\mathbf{x}\|^2$. Solving $f'(a) = 0$ we obtain

$$
a = \frac{\mathbf{x}^T\hat{\mathbf{y}}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}
$$

In general, I find that working in terms of vectors and matrices is much easier and less messy than working with summations.

Comment: Thanks. It looks clearer. Could you also explain this "some calculus"? I would greatly appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Your $\frac \sigma {\sigma a}$ should read $\frac d{da}$ or $\frac \partial {\partial a}$.  Then at the first equal sign you put the $2$ in the denominator, not the numerator and lost an overall minus sign.  Neither of these will matter because you are going to set it to zero.  At the second equal sign you lost the $x_i$ that should multiply $y_i$.  After all that, you should have $$\frac {d\epsilon}{da}=\frac 2m\sum_{i=1}^n(ax_i^2-x_iy_i)$$ which you set to zero.  If you separate the two terms into separate sums and distribute out the factor $a$ you get an equation you can solve for $a$